AT+CPOL? returns CME ERROR 22 on certain SIM cards
As part of a test in some GSM devices, I'm running AT+CPOL? to read the preferred operator list. It's supposed to then write and delete from that list, but it's failing at the first step of reading the list, it returns CME ERROR 22: not found.
I have tried running the commands manually and it returns CME ERROR 22 every time in a few of my SIM cards. I've tried using my personal SIM card and everything goes fine, I can read and write the list without any error.
In the SIM card returning the error, I have also tried using the AT+CPLS command to change to the operator given PLMN list and the HPLMN list and the terminal can read both of those lists. It's just the default user one that is giving problems.
These are some of the commands I executed in the device:
AT
OK
AT+CMEE=2
OK
AT+CPOL?
+CME ERROR: not found
AT+CPOL=1,2,"26201"
+CME ERROR: not found
AT+CPOL?
+CME ERROR: not found
AT+CPOL=?
+CME ERROR: not found
AT+CMEE=1
OK
AT+CPOL?
+CME ERROR: 22
AT+CPLS=1
OK
AT+CPOL?
+CPOL: 1,0,"3",0,0,1,0

+CPOL: 2,0,"3",1,0,1,0

+CPOL: 3,0,"3",1,0,1,1

OK
AT+CPLS=0
OK
AT+CPOL?
+CME ERROR: 22

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue or is it just that the SIM card is wrong and I should change it to a new one?
